# Find maximum of a function of a complex argument

Tags: complex-analysis

I'd like to find the maximum of a (real) function of a complex argument. However, the function contains the $\Re(z)$ operator, so that the question is

$$\operatorname{argmax}_z f(z,\overline{z})$$

Is it admissible to use something like

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}=0$$
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \overline{z}}=0$$

Or what else can I use here?

EDIT:
The function is slightly complicated, however, I'm also interested if these derivatives (Wirtinger?) are correct to find the maximum in general. The function is (mostly likely)

$$f(z,\overline{z})=\sum_i \frac{g(y_i)}{1+\exp\left(-\Re\left(\frac{a\cdot y_i}{z\cdot y_i+1}\right)\right)}$$

with all complex numbers. The $y_i$ are a sequence of complex numbers and the function $g(y)$ is known.

Are there any other methods to solve this problem?

Comment: Do you have an expression for $f$?

Comment: If you want to eliminate the *complexity* (pun intended), you can write $z = x + iy$ and $\bar{z} = x - iy$ and change variables to get a function of *real variables* $g(x,y) = f(x + iy, x - iy)$.

Comment: $\Re(z)$ will change the argument for different values of $z$. However, nothing can be said for sure without the expression for the function.